# I18N Rendering as EN-US and not Neutral Culture

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, internationalization

I am using MVC 4, C# and Razor to build a website but am having a problem with regards to implementing Internationalisation.

After following [Nadeem Afana's](http://afana.me/post/aspnet-mvc-internationalization.aspx) blog on Internationalisation I have successfully implemented 90% of the English context correctly. However, I am having an issue with the resources working in the Error View (example code below).

```
<h1 class="grey lighter smaller">
  <span class="blue bigger-125">
    <i class="icon-warning-sign"></i>
      @Resources.ErrorMessage
  </span>
</h1>
```

When an Error is thrown (whether a 404 or 500) it redirects to the error controller and renders the necessary view based on the handled exception (example below). Yet, unlike the rest of the pages it is try to convert the language to **en-us**, the rest of the website converts it to **en** only and the latter is the correct format.

```
public ActionResult ServerError()
{
    Response.StatusCode = (int) HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError;
    return View();
}
```

I have code within a helper which is meant to strip off the second part of the culture (e.g. 'us') if it doesn't exist in the database (example below)

```
public static string GetNeutralCulture(string name)
{
  if (name.Length > 2)
  {
    return name;
  }

  return name.Substring(0, 2);
}
```

From the above I understand that the website cannot convert the language to 'en-us' as no data exists for it within the database. But that doesn't resolve why it is converting it to 'us' when I have specified to strip the language to it Neutal Culture within the helper if it isn't supported. As I am out of ideas on how to rectify the problem, can someone give me some advice.

Oh and I have checked the master pages to ensure the main language of the website is set as `<html lang="en">` so as to rule the possibility of this being an issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After coming back into work this morning, I had another look over the above problem. The issue wasn't so much with my code but more with the primary `web.config` file missing a key element.

When an error was encountered it would redirect the user through the customErrors portion of the web.config file (below) then pass it to the controller accordingly.

```
<customErrors mode="On" defaultRedirect="/ServerError?">
  <error statusCode="401" redirect="/InvalidUser?" />
  <error statusCode="403" redirect="/InvalidUser?" />
  <error statusCode="404" redirect="/PageNotFound?" />
</customErrors>
```

By default web.config will use `en-us` as the primary language, whether you have specified 'en, es, fr' (etc) as the supported languages (outside of web.config). To remedy the situation, all you need to add within the `<system.web>` is something similar to the below code.

```
<globalization
  enableClientBasedCulture="true"
  requestEncoding="utf-8"
  responseEncoding="utf-8"
  culture="en"
  uiCulture="en"/>
```

Source: [Globalization Element (ASP.NET Settings Schema)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hy4kkhe0%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)